# How to use try Exception block to save my code from abnormal termination?

Tags: python, authentication, ftp, ftplib

I'm writing a program that connects to my website via ftp. If the login authentication fails, I want it to continue on to do something else. But an authentication failure error automatically exits the program. Is there a way to ignore this and continue on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's Exception Handling:

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception, ex:
    print "The process failed because", ex
    do_something_else()
```

replace do_something() with code you first want to try.. Replace do_somthing_else() code with what you wish to try when do_something() part fails

[Reference for Exception Handling](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html)